# VS Code: Python program debugs properly, but shows "Unable to find python module" in the output, even though I am not importing anything

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

```
print("Hellooo")
```

This is my python code which I want to run in debugger.
It runs perfectly with code runner, or using terminal.
But in when I run it in debugger mode (Run -> Start Debugging), it shows this output

[VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv9U4.png)

I don't understand why it is showing "Unable to find python module" when I am not even importing any.

This is my launch.json

```
{
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    }
```

I have installled all python extensions in vscode properly, and my python location is also appropriate.

EDIT: I tried command line debugging using one of the answers, but no luck.

[Debugging using Commnad Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv3id.png)

Comment: How did you debug the python file? Running command in integrated Terminal or clicking **Run->Start Debugging** from the top option. If is the former way, please post complete screenshot.

Comment: Please check my answer update and see if it gives some inspiration to you.

Answer (score 1):

You might have multiple instances of Python interpreter installed. I had the same issue with debugger, and it turns out python.exe in my mingw64 installation was overriding my default Python installation path.

Which might be the reason the debugger was unable to find python module initially, even though it runs normally.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpreter might have defaulted to a different interpreter. You can change this by:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> `Python: Select Interpreter`

Comment: A key note here is that each vscode workspace/folder can have its own Python interpreter chosen. I was confused because one vscode workspace was pointing to one Python interpreter (where I had added the module in question) and another was pointing to another Python interpreter (which didn't have the module).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the module `debugpy` to debug python code, what you need to do is installing the module by the following command in integrated Terminal

```
pip install debugpy
```

After its successful installation, the debugger command line syntax is as follows:

```
python -m debugpy
    --listen | --connect
    [<host>:]<port>
    [--wait-for-client]
    [--configure-<name> <value>]...
    [--log-to <path>] [--log-to-stderr]
    <filename> | -m <module> | -c <code> | --pid <pid>
    [<arg>]...
```

Here's an example for my project:

```
python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:0 ./files/b.py
```

[image]

More information please view [Debugging python in VS Code -- Command Line Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_command-line-debugging).

**[UPDATE]**

Check if there's some modules missing in your local python environment, which can be verified by installing another version of python. Another important thing is **adding Python to PATH**. These two paths should be added to **Environment Variables--PATH:**

```
\installation path\Python\Scripts\
\installation path\Python\
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because of MINGW being the interpreter for python.
use ctrl+ shift + p and type interpreter, choose select interpreters. if you don't have any interpreters other then MINGW, refer to this link [vs code environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)
and install anaconda or venv. You will get more option of interpreters. This will solve the issue