VScode "import debugpy" failing
As I had faced a problem with my python debugger, I located a debugee.py file which seemed to be the root of the problem. C:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\launcher
In that file, I noticed that import debugpy looked like this: image
I tried pip uninstalling debugpy and reinstalling it, but to no avail, and importing debugpy in the terminal seems to have no issues, which lead me to suspect that the problem is with VScode. I have also tried uninstalling Vscode and removing all files associated with it, but the problem persisted.
If anyone knows why this problem exists or how to fix it, your help will be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
The original issue was that the VScode python debugger outputted:ouput in the terminal when trying to debug any code. I tried reinstalling the debugpy extension multiple times, but it didn't seem to fix anything. Moreover, I believe that the debugee file is the root of the issue as it tries to access debugpy six times, which my correlate with the messages in the terminal.
EDIT 2: Thank you for all the help, my VScode debugger works now. It turns out that the path to python.exe was the system python in C:\msys64\bin\python.exe and not the python in ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe

"I had faced a problem with my python debugger, I located a debugee.py file which seemed to be the root of the problem" I think you might be headed into an XY problem. To make sure, what was the original issue with the Python debugger? What was your launch.json? How are you running the program and launching the debugger? I think that's the more pertinent issue. The debugpy is managed by the VS Code Python debugger extension, you're not supposed to be directly tinkering around with it. Have you tried reinstalling the extension?

"Unable to find python" module means VS Code cannot find your Python installation on your system. See VS Code docs on configuring your Python environment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. There is a "Select Interpreter" command, and then point it to your Python installation, especially if you multiple environments.

Check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68769412/2745495
